# How to change the object when importing data in R

Tags: r

I have an Excel file containing a column of 10000 numbers that I wish to import into R.

However, no matter the method I use, the resulting object is either a list of 1, or 10000 obs. of 1 variable (I have used read.csv on the .csv version of the file, read_xlsx on the .xlsx version). If this is expected, how can I work these objects into ordinary arrays?

I have tried importing the same files into matlab and everything is working normally there (it's immediately an ordinary array).

Comment: Have you tried other delimiters besides a comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an excel file you might want to try the `readxl` package.

```
library("readxl")

dt <- read_excel("your_file_path")
```

[link](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/reference/read_excel.html)

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, I think it is normal that if you import one column file you get an atomic vector, that is 1 var with 10000 obs...

Answer (score 0):

Found an easy method:
convert data to a dataframe, and then convert it to an array;

```
my_data<-data.frame(my_data)
my_data<-data.matrix(my_data)
```